# Python: Invalid AWS Access key error

Tags: php, python, amazon-web-services

I am using the following example code to fetch details. And it's giving error:

> amazonproduct.errors.InvalidClientTokenId: InvalidClientTokenId: The
>   AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

The same is working while I used in PHP. I generated the key going to [IAM Console.](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/)

```
access_key = '***'
secret_key = '***'
associate_tag = 'ptab-20'
api = API(locale='us')
    result = api.item_lookup('B006H3MIV8')
    for item in result.Items.Item:
        print '%s (%s)' % (item.ItemAttributes.Title, item.ASIN)
```

Comment: newbie lesson #1: don't put live keys/passwords on stackoverflow

Comment: Where are you passing your access and secret keys to your `API()`? Also what is `API()`? Please dd import statement for `API()` too.

Comment: @fire I did it deliberately as often was asked to pass on credentials. Since this keys were going to be removed anyway in a few hours so I posted it.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir I am trying to follow this: http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic-usage.html#basic-setup

Comment: @Volatil3 try `api = API(AWS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, "us")` instead of putting key and secret in a conf file and see if it works. If it does then it means `API` is not able to read your conf file somehow.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir Yes!!! it works. Doc is misleading I guess. Pls make it your answer so that others can also get benefit from it.

Comment: `python-amazon-product-api` should consider config file. Don't know why it is not considering it.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow `python-amazon-product-api` is not considering the config file i.e. `~/.amazon-product-api`. Alternatively you can specify your credentials directly when instantiating `API` object by

```
api = API(AWS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, "us")
```

Comment: The problem is, this is now deprecated.